# Nordic characters escaped in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, razor, asp.net-core

I'm stuck on a problem I can't seem to solve. On the back-end I'm using ASP.NET Core 2.0, from a Controller to a View using ViewBag sending an array containing a couple of words. E.g. "These", "Are", "Överdrivna", "Påse".

Using the following Razor code in my view i loop out the results

```
@foreach (var words in ViewBag.Words)
{
    <span>@words.word</span>
}
```

However i want to send the contents of this array into a JavaScript array and this is where the trouble starts. E.g. if I do this:

```
<script>
console.log("åäö"); <-- this works
@foreach (var words in ViewBag.Words)
{
console.log('@words.word');
}
</script>
```

The words without nordic characters show up correctly in the console, e.g. "These". However when the word/words with "ÅÄÖ" are to be printed out I get them printed out as `"p&#xE5;se"` instead of "påse".

All my views and files are saved as UTF-8 (double checked with both Visual Studio and Notepad++). And as stated above, it prints out just fine when not using JavaScript.

What could I be doing wrong, and how can i fix it?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: For the moment to solve this I loop out the results into a hidden select-box instead, fetch the values and put them into a JavaScript array. It seems that somehow it's Razor that causes this problem. My solution works but it ain't pretty. :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the Javascript Encoder;

Add the reference for Encodings:

```
@using System.Text.Encodings.Web
```

And then:

```
 @foreach (var words in ViewBag.Words)
    {
       @:  console.log("@JavaScriptEncoder.Default.Encode(@words)"); 
    }
```